# Using hapi and handlebars, with the default layout support from hapi, can alternative layout be selected from with a page?

Tags: templates, layout, handlebars.js, hapi.js

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757616/how-to-get-handlebar-layouts-working-in-node-hapi-js/26760915#26760915) and the hapi api indicate that hapi has built in support for layouts when using handles bars.  It seems however, to only allow one layout defined in the config as an alternative to the default 'layout.html' layout.

In [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757616/how-to-get-handlebar-layouts-working-in-node-hapi-js/26760915#26760915) it is shown how to use handlebars-layouts to use the handlebars layout support to do this within a page like so:

```
{{#extend "layout2"}}{{/extend}}
```

While I am able to use handlebars-layouts, I would like to just use as much built in stuff which hapi provides.

Is it possible then to have more than the default layout and select that layout in a page template?  Maybe like this:

```
{{!< layout/layout2}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the views manager configuration in [`reply.view()`](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#replyviewtemplate-context-options):

> `options` - optional object used to override the server's views manager configuration for this response. Cannot override `isCached`, `partialsPath`, or `helpersPath` which are only loaded at initialization.

Here is an example:

index.js:

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Path = require('path');

var server = new Hapi.Server()
server.connection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8000
});

server.views({
    engines: {
        html: Handlebars.create()
    },
    path: Path.join(__dirname, 'views'),
    layoutPath: Path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts'),
    layout: 'default'
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/default',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        reply.view('item', { title: 'Item Title', body: 'Item Body' });
    }
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/custom',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        reply.view('item', { title: 'Item Title', body: 'Item Body' }, { layout: 'custom' });
    }
});

server.start();
```

views/layouts/custom.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Custom Layout</h1>
    {{{content}}}
 </body>
</html>
```

views/layouts/default.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Default Layout</h1>
    {{{content}}}
 </body>
</html>
```

views/item.html:

```
{{body}}
```

When you visit http://localhost:8000/default, it will use `default.html`. However http://localhost:8000/custom will use `custom.html`.

Comment: Nice!  Though I was hoping to define the layout in the page.. I can work with that.  Thanks!